# I command you, you all bow down before me

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Really I'm nothing special, I'm as common as anything else.
> Even if you are careful, You may turn out ruining myself.
>
> Dear to many, hated by few.
> Here is plenty, you'll need to chew.
>
> Even the devout can't abstain from me, though they may try.
> Relaxing and enjoying me is the key, you'll sure to buy.
>
> Read the instructions or beware, I'll turn out terrible for sure.
> I can be presented with fanfare, or with nothing and remain pure.
>
> Now is the time to guess what I am, I'll put a smile on your face.
> Give me all your money so you may cram, use and leave me without a trace.

What am I?

Comment: RED HERING?${}$ I like... :)

Comment: I double checked my spelling, there are two R's, but yes. That's not the answer though. (laughs maniacally)

Comment: I know there are two R's, but idc. It is a good riddle, and it's making me think... hmmm

Comment: If I have another guess, should I add it to my previous answer, or a new answer?

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie, if it's different enough, I always prefer people to post another answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are...

> Food!

Really I'm nothing special, I'm as common as anything else.

> In some countries/cultures, food is bountiful and common to see everywhere you go.

Even if you are careful, You may turn out ruining myself.

> It's easy to ruin food in a multitude of ways when cooking, reheating, seasoning, transporting, etc. You can accidentally drop a plate of food on the floor and ruin all of it, or let it sit too long so that it gets too cold.

Dear to many, hated by few.

> Since food is necessary to live, most people love it. Unfortunately, there are some people who do not like food either due to eating disorders or personal taste preferences.

Here is plenty, you'll need to chew.

> You have to chew your food when you eat it. The more you have in your mouth, the more you have to chew before you swallow.

Even the devout can't abstain from me, though they may try.

> Many people that are devout in their religion will fast (abstain) from food for periods of time. They eventually have to eat again though.

Relaxing and enjoying me is the key, you'll sure to buy.

> People like to buy food that's already made so that they can just relax, eat, and enjoy it without the work of making it.

Read the instructions or beware, I'll turn out terrible for sure.

> If you don't follow the recipe correctly when making food, it can turn out pretty bad!

I can be presented with fanfare, or with nothing and remain pure.

> Food can be a really big show in and of itself, such as through presentation on a dish or as the main focus of a social event. Food can also be as simple as a quick snack. Either way, food is still food.

Now is the time to guess what I am, I'll put a smile on your face.

> Eating good food leaves people satisfied and happy.

Give me all your money so you may cram, use and leave me without a trace.

> Buy food, cram it all in (or eat it), then leave empty dishes with no trace of the food.

Bonus Clue

> The first letter of each line spells Red Herring. This actually is NOT a Red Herring in the sense of being a "misleading clue". Red Herring is in fact a type of fish that has been prepared as food.

Edit - I forgot to explain the title!

I command you, you all bow down before me

> Our hunger typically "commands" us. When we get hungry, we need to eat, so we end up setting everything aside to focus on food. Also, some people/religions pray when sitting around the table to eat, which may include bowing heads "before the food".

Comment: Ha ha! you got it! Great job! I was wondering when someone was going to figure out that the hidden clue was real! :D

Comment: Awesome! I think this is the first time I've actually been able to figure out the answer to a riddle that someone else hasn't already posted an answer to.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Rule?

Really I'm nothing special, I'm as common as anything else.

> Rules are normal to have.

Even if you are careful, You may turn out ruining myself.

> You may break a rule without noticing.

Dear to many, hated by few.

> Criminals hate laws.

Here is plenty, you'll need to chew.

> Rules every where?

Even the devout can't abstain from me, though they may try.

> They still have rules and laws.

Relaxing and enjoying me is the key, you'll sure to buy.

> Sure?

Read the instructions or beware, I'll turn out terrible for sure.

> You may follow it wrong.

I can be presented with fanfare, or with nothing and remain pure.

> Yep.

Now is the time to guess what I am, I'll put a smile on your face.

> Knowing they may keep people safe from steeling and other things.

Give me all your money so you may cram, use and leave me without a trace.

> ?

I command you, you all bow down before me

> Rules

Hidden clue

> The first letter of every sentence says RED HERRING.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, but it's not the answer I'm looking for. The last line especially doesn't fit this answer. The answer is physical.

Comment: The one and only time that quantumtwinkie is not correct

Answer (score 3):

Just pointing it out, the first letters of each line spells out

> Red herring, which is obviously what it says, a red herring, LOL

Answer (score 3):

Really I'm nothing special, I'm as common as anything else.
Even if you are careful, You may turn out ruining myself.

> common thing and pretty easy to ruin, life?

Dear to many, hated by few.

> some hold their lives dear while some hates theirs

Here is plenty, you'll need to chew.

> life is too much to handle, take it easy?

Comment: Another good answer, but not the one I'm looking for. Again, the last line doesn't really fit with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

> We are all commanded by the demands of "Time" and in the end we all bow down before it. And since we can't take money with us when we go, we might at well put it to use and hopefully for the benefit of those we must leave behind. My answer is Time*

Comment: Not a bad guess, but again, not the answer I'm looking for. As mentioned in a previous comment, the answer is more physical. It's a thing, not a concept or idea.

Comment: *Figured that chewing time didn't make sense lol. Ah back to the drawing board.*

Answer (score 1):

> A book

Really I'm nothing special, I'm as common as anything else.

> Books are an incredibly common item today.

Even if you are careful, You may turn out ruining myself.

> You can spill a drink on your book, leaves crumbs in it, stains of all kinds- and if it's a written one, you might smear the words if you don't lift your hands up.

Dear to many, hated by few.

> Most people like books, but there are always a few who don't.

Here is plenty, you'll need to chew.

> Hmm... those gross kids who eat paper ripped out of textbooks?

Even the devout can't abstain from me, though they may try.

> Bible

Relaxing and enjoying me is the key, you'll sure to buy.

> Read for relaxation. Read for enjoyment. Harry Potter.

Read the instructions or beware, I'll turn out terrible for sure.

> Different kind of book- cookbook? Instructions manual?

I can be presented with fanfare, or with nothing and remain pure.

> Fanfiction, mmmm. It doesn't have to be 50 shades of gray, though.

Now is the time to guess what I am, I'll put a smile on your face.

> Those moments in the book that make you grin

Give me all your money so you may cram, use and leave me without a trace.

> college books or books that are used for schooling.

I command you, you all bow down before me

> If you're talkin' Bible, it's a pretty powerful book. Any book written by a figure of importance *coughkampf* could be a symbol of power.

Comment: Another good guess, but not the answer. Here is plenty, you'll need to chew doesn't really fit this answer. But to be fair, this answer is the closest so far (though still pretty far off).

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't the chewing reference I thought it was. *shudders*

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Tobacco

This is because it

> is common, can be ruined, few hate it,   etc. etc.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! When answering questions, please ensure to hide your answers in spoiler tags >! so that other puzzlers attempting to solve this puzzle will not see your answer! Thanks!